# Is there another way to return null or another keywords when selecting null values in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have tried using IFNULL(column, 'NULL') as column but its not working and so is COALESCE but they are both returning blank on the front end with no error.

```
"SELECT IFNULL(date_reassigned, 'N/A') as date_reassigned, case_no, parties.defendant as defendant, parties.claimant as claimant, description, court_date_assigned, status.name as status, users.firstname as firstname, users.lastname as lastname, new_judge, date_registered , users_username FROM cases INNER JOIN parties ON(cases.parties_id=parties.id) INNER JOIN users ON(cases.users_username=users.username) INNER JOIN status ON(cases.status_id=status.id) WHERE cases.date_added >=? AND cases.date_added <=? AND status_id=? ORDER BY cases.date_added DESC"
```

Comment: If *they are both returning blank* then the column contains blanks and not nulls.

Comment: Both ifnull and coalesce should work. So, rather than asking for new way, you should focus on finding out what's wrong with your current approach. I would say you may have blank values and not nulls where you expect nulls.

Comment: But then if i select using the mysql console am getting null

Comment: you should check if the column is really NULL because it works see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e6bb1f511328be2babf37a696b031c3b

Comment: And what if you use coalesce in the mysql console?

Comment: Interesting, punching the same Select query in the MYSQL  console using IFNULL and COALESCE  its returning N/A but not on my site. So i guess the problem is my backend

Answer (score 0):

The column is empty/blank not null in this  case .
(Might be '').
use this below approach .

```
  select ifnull(if(date_reassigned='','N/A',date_reassigned),'N/A') from 
  table_name;
```

Comment: It is returning blank when i used it in php and N/A when i use it directly in mysql

Comment: write an if condition in php whenever its blank replace it with 'N/A'.

Comment: Thank you. I will do it in php